# Error drawing route on maps

Tags: android, maps, fragment

I'm following a [tutorial](http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-draw-path-two-points-using-google-directions-google-map-android-api-v2/) to implement route drawing on my map. I implemented it, run it, choose points and then it crashes. It gives me this error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions)' on a null object reference

The thing is that this shouldn't be empty since I have at least 3 points on the map....
The studio points my error to be here, but I dont find it: `protected void onPostExecute(List>> result) {
            ArrayList points;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }


            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(10);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

        }
        if(lineOptions != null) {
            googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions); //---> ERROR supose to be here..
        }
        else {

        }
    }
}`
```

If anybody could give me a hand, I would kindly appreciate it.

Comment: can you show where you are initializing googleMap object?

Comment: @Rahil2952 Done, on edit you have it.

Comment: I am not asking about MapFragment. On this line "googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);" you are trying to use googleMap show me where it is initialized?

Comment: I have it right after defining the class, on the global variables `private GoogleMap googleMap;`

Comment: That's you are creating instance and by default it will be null. You need to initialize it in your code. Go through code in tutorial you mentioned they are initializing it in "  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)" method follow it and understand it properly.

Comment: Thanks mate, it works. I would give you correct answer if you would post it as such.

Comment: By the way, @Rahil2952 Any clue about drawing the route for walkers instead of cars?

Comment: Follow this link and you can achieve what you want. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#TravelModes